# Deserialize JSON from an API that returns the same object with some properties null

Tags: c#, json

i'm using this api: https://store.steampowered.com/api/appdetails?appids=847370 that returns a json object and i've created a model to deserialize it.

But there's an difference on json, if the game has mac or linux requirements, then it returns an { } object, but if it don't have, then it return an [ ].

So my problem is, i've created a model using json2charp.com and deserialized many requests, but if it don't have mac or linux requirements, then the json throws error on deserialize.

My Model:

```
public class RootObject : Dictionary<string, AppRoot>
{

}

public class AppRoot
{
    public bool success { get; set; }
    public Data data { get; set; }
}
public class PcRequirements
{
    public string minimum { get; set; }
    public string recommended { get; set; }
}

public class MacRequirements
{
    public string minimum { get; set; }
    public string recommended { get; set; }
}

public class LinuxRequirements
{
    public string minimum { get; set; }
    public string recommended { get; set; }
}

public class PriceOverview
{
    public string currency { get; set; }
    public int initial { get; set; }
    public int final { get; set; }
    public int discount_percent { get; set; }
    public string initial_formatted { get; set; }
    public string final_formatted { get; set; }
}

public class Sub
{
    public int packageid { get; set; }
    public string percent_savings_text { get; set; }
    public int percent_savings { get; set; }
    public string option_text { get; set; }
    public string option_description { get; set; }
    public string can_get_free_license { get; set; }
    public bool is_free_license { get; set; }
    public int price_in_cents_with_discount { get; set; }
}

public class PackageGroup
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string title { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public string selection_text { get; set; }
    public string save_text { get; set; }
    public int display_type { get; set; }
    public string is_recurring_subscription { get; set; }
    public List<Sub> subs { get; set; }
}

public class Platforms
{
    public bool windows { get; set; }
    public bool mac { get; set; }
    public bool linux { get; set; }
}

public class Metacritic
{
    public int score { get; set; }
    public string url { get; set; }
}

public class Category
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
}

public class Genre
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
}

public class Screenshot
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string path_thumbnail { get; set; }
    public string path_full { get; set; }
}

public class Webm
{
    public string __invalid_name__480 { get; set; }
    public string max { get; set; }
}

public class Movie
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string thumbnail { get; set; }
    public Webm webm { get; set; }
    public bool highlight { get; set; }
}

public class Recommendations
{
    public int total { get; set; }
}

public class Highlighted
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string path { get; set; }
}

public class Achievements
{
    public int total { get; set; }
    public List<Highlighted> highlighted { get; set; }
}

public class ReleaseDate
{
    public bool coming_soon { get; set; }
    public string date { get; set; }
}

public class SupportInfo
{
    public string url { get; set; }
    public string email { get; set; }
}

public class ContentDescriptors
{
    public List<int> ids { get; set; }
    public string notes { get; set; }
}

public class Data
{
    public string type { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public int steam_appid { get; set; }
    public string required_age { get; set; }
    public bool is_free { get; set; }
    public string controller_support { get; set; }
    public string detailed_description { get; set; }
    public string about_the_game { get; set; }
    public string short_description { get; set; }
    public string supported_languages { get; set; }
    public string header_image { get; set; }
    public string website { get; set; }
    public PcRequirements pc_requirements { get; set; }
    public MacRequirements mac_requirements { get; set; }
    public LinuxRequirements linux_requirements { get; set; }
    public string legal_notice { get; set; }
    public List<string> developers { get; set; }
    public List<string> publishers { get; set; }
    public PriceOverview price_overview { get; set; }
    public List<int> packages { get; set; }
    public List<PackageGroup> package_groups { get; set; }
    public Platforms platforms { get; set; }
    public Metacritic metacritic { get; set; }
    public List<Category> categories { get; set; }
    public List<Genre> genres { get; set; }
    public List<Screenshot> screenshots { get; set; }
    public List<Movie> movies { get; set; }
    public Recommendations recommendations { get; set; }
    public Achievements achievements { get; set; }
    public ReleaseDate release_date { get; set; }
    public SupportInfo support_info { get; set; }
    public string background { get; set; }
    public ContentDescriptors content_descriptors { get; set; }
}
```

**Can't include json sample here, the limit will be reached, sorry. Just open it on browser, it works.**

JSON With Mac Requirements (That work with my model)

https://store.steampowered.com/api/appdetails?appids=847370

JSON Without MAC Requirements (Throws error, can't deserialize on my custom model)

https://store.steampowered.com/api/appdetails?appids=731490

Is there a way to create a unique model to support these different requests? or configure deserialize?

Comment: What library are you using to do the deserialization?

Comment: NewtonSoft.Json.
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);

Answer (score 0):

What you'll need in this situation, since you're dealing with a non-standard API that should be returning `null` rather than an empty array, is a custom [JsonConverter](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CustomJsonConverter.htm).

I've created a proof-of-concept that should work in your situation:

```
public class NullValueArrayConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.StartArray)
        {
            reader.Read(); //Advances to the next character so that the ArrayClose token is ignored.
            return null;
        }

        return serializer.Deserialize(reader, objectType);
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        serializer.Serialize(writer, value);
    }
}
```

Then you just need to decorate the properties in your model accordingly:

```
public class Data
{
    //...
    [JsonConverter(typeof(NullValueArrayConverter))]
    public PcRequirements pc_requirements { get; set; }
    [JsonConverter(typeof(NullValueArrayConverter))]
    public MacRequirements mac_requirements { get; set; }
    [JsonConverter(typeof(NullValueArrayConverter))]
    public LinuxRequirements linux_requirements { get; set; }
    //...
}
```